# Call super of infix operator

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call super.+= operator, but I get a compiler error. I looked for the correct syntax / way to do it without success.

If we have, for instance

```
class a {
  var item1: Int

  static func += (left: inout a, right: a) {left.item1 += right.item1;}
}

class b : a {
  var item2 : Int;
  
  static func += (left: inout b, right: b) {  
    super.+=(left: left as a, right: right as a)  <-- compile issue
    left.item2 += right.item2;
  }
}
```

Can someone please point out the correct syntax for this to work?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators are statically dispatched (see how they are marked `static`?) That means they are dispatched solely based on the compile-time types of the operands. Operators don't override each other like instance methods do, and so there is no need to call `super`.

If the operands' compile-time type are the super type, then the super type's operator will be called.

In this case, just casting `right` to `A` suffices, because `B`'s operator cannot be called with an `A` as its second operand.

Another thing is that you don't need the first operands to be `inout`, because these are classes, not structs. Only value type parameters, like structs, need `inout` in order for you to modify their values inside the operator function.

Having the copy-in-copy-out semantic of `inout` present here will make it a lot harder to call from the subclass.

Here's the code with everything fixed:

```
class A {
    var item1: Int
    
    init(item1: Int) {
        self.item1 = item1
    }

    static func += (left: A, right: A) { left.item1 += right.item1 }
}

class B : A {
    var item2 : Int
    
    init(item1: Int, item2: Int) {
        self.item2 = item2
        super.init(item1: item1)
    }
  
    static func += (left: B, right: B) {
        left += right as A
        left.item2 += right.item2;
    }
}

let x = B(item1: 2, item2: 3)
let y = B(item1: 1, item2: 1)
x += y
print(x.item1, x.item2) // 3 4
print(y.item1, y.item2) // 1 1
```

Note that it is possible to do:

```
let x = B(item1: 2, item2: 3)
let y: A = B(item1: 2, item2: 3)
x += y
```

and `x` would have `item1: 4, item2: 3`.This is because operators are dispatched statically, based on compile time types. If that is undesirable, perhaps don't put operators on non-final classes.